# How implement windowDrawSystemBarBackgrounds and statusBarColor on older API's, i.e. v19?

Tags: android, xml

My main activity extends AppCompatActivity, and I'm using support toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

I want to color the toolbar using the windowsDrawSystemBarBackground and statusBarColor attributes, which works fine in >=v21:

[image: Base Application Theme]

But all hell breaks loose when trying to run on v19, namely:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ca.toadlybroodledev.sublist/ca.toadlybroodledev.sublist.ActivityMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

Seems that all Log errors are passed null messages? Really baffled by this.

Here's my main activity layout, which also has an extended DrawerLayout as it's root:

```
<ca.toadlybroodledev.sublist.DrawerCustomLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- The ActionBar displayed at the top when drawer is shown -->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/placeholder_for_fragments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer that comes from the left -->
<!-- Note that `android:layout_gravity` needs to be set to 'start' -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nvView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_item_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_item_color"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</ca.toadlybroodledev.sublist.DrawerCustomLayout>
```

I've tried creating a seperate style (v21) resource, which works for API's >= 21, but doesn't solve the underlying backwards compatibility problem. I've also tried removing "android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" from the toolbar, no difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, correctly implementing versioned Andoid Styles and Themes has for some reason always eluded me...

[Edit 1] If anyone is interested, I was finally able to build for v19 without minifying by adding this to the build file:

```
dexOptions { javaMaxHeapSize "2g" }
```

and here's the stack trace I'm getting now:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...ActMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
                  at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
                  at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:139)
                  at ca.toadlybroodledev.sublist.ActMain.updateColors(ActMain.java:404)
                  at ca.toadlybroodledev.sublist.DrawerCustomLayout.onFinishInflate(DrawerCustomLayout.java:50)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
                  at ca.toadlybroodledev.sublist.ActMain.onCreate(ActMain.java:77)
```

Comment: What line causes the NPE? Please post the entire stacktrace.

Comment: Haha I was hoping to avoid that as my classes appear to be obfuscated atm due to having to minify to successfully build for v19...but that's another problem all together.

Comment: I have the following rule in my debug proguard file, but for some reason it's still obfuscating my classes?
-keep class ca.toadlybroodledev.sublist

Comment: Ok so I was finally able to build for v19 without minifying by adding this to the build file: dexOptions { javaMaxHeapSize "2g" }

Answer (score 0):

You can only change  the color of statusbar from Lollipop
If you want to change the color of statusbar for Api >= 19 you need this inside the style of value-v19 check the files you need to specific versions(olders):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

        <style name="AppTheme" parent="MaterialDrawerTheme.Light">
                <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
                <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
                <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
                .....
        </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense, but when I do this I'm getting error:

Comment: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'MaterialDrawerTheme.Light'.